# Why second controller doesn't work in asp.net webApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

I would like to have second controller in my asp.net WebApi, but when i add it it not works... First Controller works OK

i have 404 not found in my browser

- not any errors while run

whats wrong?

```
namespace testing.Controllers
   {
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering",           
   "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

and the second is below

```
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public int Get()
        {
            return 100050;
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: i have 404 not found ;/

Comment: What url did you use?

Comment: i mean that code is fine, but i can't see this side in browser

Comment: https://localhost:5001/ValuesController/

Comment: https://localhost:5001/calculator/

Comment: calculator works , values controller not

Comment: Take off the word "Controller" from your url. See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area

Comment: ...... sorry im beginner ... you can give it as answer, i will give you best

Comment: You must access only: localhost:5001/Values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the attribute `[Route("[controller]")]` on your controller class. The string `[controller]` means "the name of the class, **without the actual WORD "Controller"**.

This means, the name of the controller is "Values" (or "WeatherForecast" for the previous controller).

So, the final url route you want is `/Values`, not `/ValuesController`.

You can read more about how this works on the [MS Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) (the whole page has a lot of good information, not just that section).

Answer (score 0):

There is another web server here that will forward request /weatherforecast to kestrel web server which host your controller.

Edit /ClientApp/setupProxy.js, change `/weatherforecast` to `/api/**`

```
const context =  [
  "/api/**",
];
```

Edit Program.cs, add `api/` to the path

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Edit MyController.cs, add `api/` to route

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

Alternatively, you could remove the SpaProxy and serve the static pages directly from the kestrel web server.